# How to delete multiple UIButton or particular UIButton dynamically created?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

In my application , on a UIButton Click, I need to dynamically create multiple UIButtons and execute methods for that.

How to delete a particular UIButton from the UIButtons created? 
By backspace key press or delete key press? Or is there any other way to delete the UIButton?

my source code for create

in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *selectedBtnarr;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)Check
{
    CGPoint origin = note.frame.origin;
    NSString* head = [note.text substringToIndex:note.selectedRange.location];
    CGSize initialSize = [head sizeWithFont:note.font constrainedToSize:note.contentSize];
    NSUInteger startOfLine = [head length];

    NSString* tail = [head substringFromIndex:startOfLine];
    CGSize lineSize = [tail sizeWithFont:note.font forWidth:note.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGPoint cursor = origin;
    cursor.x += lineSize.width + 15;
    cursor.y += initialSize.height - lineSize.height - 130;


    checkbox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cursor.x,cursor.y,15,15)];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"]forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"]forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    checkbox.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;
    [checkbox setTag:checkButtonCount];
    [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(ChkUnChk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [note addSubview:checkbox];

    NSString *xAxis=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f" ,checkbox.frame.origin.x];
    NSString *yAxis=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f" ,checkbox.frame.origin.y];
    [chkBoxX addObject:xAxis];
    [chkBoxY addObject:yAxis];
    NSString *tag=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d" ,checkButtonCount];
    [chkTag addObject:tag];
    checkButtonCount=checkButtonCount+1;

        }

-(void)ChkUnChk:(id)sender
    {
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *Str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",btn.tag];
    BOOL flag=   [selectedBtnarr containsObject:Str];

    if (flag==YES)
    {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [selectedBtnarr removeObject:Str];
    }
    else
    {
        [selectedBtnarr addObject:Str];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    }
```

but i dono how to delete this...

to delete my code is below

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    const char * _char = [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

    if (isBackSpace == -8)
    {
        NSLog(@"backspace Detected");

        CGPoint origin = note.frame.origin;
        NSString* head = [note.text substringToIndex:note.selectedRange.location];
        CGSize initialSize = [head sizeWithFont:note.font constrainedToSize:note.contentSize];
        NSUInteger startOfLine = [head length];

        NSString* tail = [head substringFromIndex:startOfLine];
        CGSize lineSize = [tail sizeWithFont:note.font forWidth:note.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        CGPoint cursor = origin;
        cursor.x += lineSize.width + 15;
        cursor.y += initialSize.height - lineSize.height - 130;

        NSLog(@"Cursor Place X : %f   Y: %f",cursor.x,cursor.y);

        int tagcoount=[chkTag count];

        for(int a=0;a<tagcoount;a++)
        {

            NSString *tag=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[chkTag objectAtIndex:a]];

            int chkcnt=[tag intValue];

            if(cursor.x==checkbox.frame.origin.x && cursor.y==checkbox.frame.origin.y && a==checkbox.tag)
                {
                    [[checkbox viewWithTag:chkcnt] removeFromSuperview];
                    [chkTag removeObjectAtIndex:chkcnt];

                }
        }
}
```

but it is deleting only the last UIButton , that too when cursor in that current position only.. give me right idea

Comment: have u checked my answer and tried downloading my code?

Comment: U wrote code with delegate.. so i don't get to download ur code

Comment: That code is in AppDelegate class, you can easily move that code to your class file...what the big deal in that?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `NSMutableArray` to store `UIButton` objects. Assign a tag number to each `UIButton` using its `setTag:` method to identify individual buttons and remove them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much..i have updated the code. please check it and say how to write for delete

Comment: Have you tried using NSLog to see what chkcnt values are being sent to [chkTag removeObjectAtIndex:chkcnt]?

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement: Kindly get the idea from my Mac [project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/view.php?id=5296188&da=y) (as am not in ios) but you will feel this handy.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property(strong)NSMutableArray *buttons;
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)remove:(id)sender;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *popUp;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *buttonView;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    _buttons=[NSMutableArray new];

}

-(void)clearButtonSubview{
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<[[_buttonView subviews]count]; i++) {
        NSView *view=[[_buttonView subviews]objectAtIndex:i];
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

-(void)drawButtons{

    //when u add, remove prev drawn and redraw all.
    [self clearButtonSubview];

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<[_buttons count]; i++) {
        NSButton *button=[_buttons objectAtIndex:i];
        [button setFrame:NSMakeRect(i*55, 10, 50, 20)];
        [_buttonView addSubview:button];

        //add buttons in popup
        [_popUp addItemWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",button.tag]];
    }

}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {

    [_popUp removeAllItems];

    NSButton *bttn=[NSButton new];
    //get last button tag
    NSInteger lastButtonTag=[[_buttons lastObject] tag];

    [bttn setTag:lastButtonTag+1];
    [bttn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[bttn tag]]];

    [_buttons addObject:bttn];

    [self drawButtons];
}

- (IBAction)remove:(id)sender {
    NSInteger indexOfButtonToRemove;
    NSString *selectedButton=[_popUp titleOfSelectedItem];

    for (NSInteger index=0;index<[_buttons count];index++) {
        NSButton *button=[_buttons objectAtIndex:index];

        if ([[button title]isEqualToString:selectedButton]) {
            indexOfButtonToRemove=index;
            break;
        }
    }

    [_buttons removeObjectAtIndex:indexOfButtonToRemove];
    [_popUp removeItemAtIndex:indexOfButtonToRemove];

    [self clearButtonSubview];
    [self drawButtons];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank u so much...i have updated my question n added my code.. please see that and say me how to delete the UIButton

Comment: In the method `check`, instead of drawing buttons in that fashion, create and array having `y`, then draw the buttons are suggested.